# Side by side monitor stand for three 32" monitors in landscape

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor-stand

I am keen to purchase a monitor stand that will allow me to have, in horizontal alignment, three 32" monitors in landscape orientation. Is this possible? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is possible. It is not gonna be very cheap though...

Two such products are:

1. [**Mount-It! Triple Monitor Mount with USB Port, Height Adjustable 3 Monitor Arm Desk Stand for 24 27 30 32 Inch LED LCD Displays (MI-2753)**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06X9D7JWP)
2. [**Amer AMR3S32 - Stand - for 3 LCD Displays**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZDX7PRU)

Also make sure the weight specs are enough for your need.